# How to get number of days between two dates in asp.net MVC using Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to get the number of days between two dates from database using Linq Query, please help me how to do this. thanks

I tried the bellow code  but it return me the result nul! please help

```
 DateTime rightNow = DateTime.Now;

        //int totalDays = (from d in db.vuExpiredProjectsAssigned
        //                 where d.AssignedTo==obj.DepartmentID
        //                 select (d.AssignedDate - d.DueDate).Days).FirstOrDefault();

        //var numberdays = (from pd in db.vuExpiredProjectsAssigned
        //                  where pd.AssignedTo == obj.DepartmentID
        //                  select SqlFunctions.DateDiff("day", pd.AssignedDate, rightNow));

       var result =(from dd in db.vuExpiredProjectsAssigned
                    where dd.AssignedTo==obj.DepartmentID
                    select new
                    {
                        days=SqlFunctions.DateDiff("Day",dd.DueDate,rightNow)
                    });

       ViewBag.ndays = result;
```

Comment: `var days = (DueDate - AssigneDate).Days;`

Comment: the error is " DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type."

Comment: Materialize the query first

Comment: check my updated code

Comment: your problem is solved?

Comment: Yes, thanks for your continuous reply

Answer (score 4):

Arithmetic with DateTime is not supported in Entity Framework. You have to use DbFunctions*. So, for the first part of your statement, something like:

```
var numberdays = ( from p in db.vuExpiredProjectsAssigned
                     where p.AssignedTo == obj.DepartmentID
                     select DbFunctions.DiffDays(p.AssignedDate,p.DueDate));
```

OR

```
var numberdays = ( from p in db.vuExpiredProjectsAssigned
                     where p.AssignedTo == obj.DepartmentID
                     select SqlFunctions.DateDiff("day", p.AssignedDate, p.DueDate));
```

For more reference please check below links.

[SqlFunctions Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx)

[DbFunctions Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.aspx)

Comment: it return an error " No overload for Method 'diffDays' takes 1 arguments " ??

Comment: what it retuns? i store the result in ViewBag it print me the query itself

Comment: it should return int array. Could you please put the break point and check that?

Comment: SELECT DATEDIFF(day, [Extent1].[AssignedDate], [Extent1].[DueDate]) AS [C1] FROM [dbo].[vuExpiredProjectsAssigned] AS [Extent1] WHERE [Extent1].[AssignedTo] = @p__linq__0

Comment: could you please convert your result into list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125268/discussion-between-zkf3340320-and-jayesh-goyani).

Comment: i tried this --- > List<string> list = new List<string>(numberdays); not working

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
DbFunctions.DiffDays(dd.DueDate,rightNow).Value
```

**Update**

```
var rightNow= DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();

public class democlass
{
 public int count {get; set;}
}
```

and query like this

```
var result =(from dd in db.vuExpiredProjectsAssigned
                where dd.AssignedTo==obj.DepartmentID
                select new democlass()
                {
                    count = DbFunctions.DiffDays(dd.DueDate,rightNow).Value
                });
```

then check your result variable.

Comment: var result = (from dd in db.vuExpiredProjectsAssigned
                          where dd.AssignedTo == obj.DepartmentID
                          select DbFunctions.DiffDays(dd.AssignedDate, dd.DueDate).Value);

            ViewBag.ndays = result;

Comment: still the return result is null

Comment: days is anonymous field?

Comment: i have a date stored in database using short format. ex . 2016-1-1,

Comment: i did but still result: null

Comment: Yes its yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: then what i should do ??

Comment: LateshtClick thanks for your reply, i found the solution

Comment: var assignedDate = db.vuExpiredProjectsAssigned.Where(xx => xx.AssignedTo == obj.DepartmentID).FirstOrDefault();
            DateTime asdate = Convert.ToDateTime(assignedDate.DueDate);
            DateTime rightNow = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now);
            TimeSpan datediff = asdate - rightNow;

            if (assignedDate.DueDate != null)
            {
                ViewBag.diff = datediff.Days.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.diff = "due date is empty";
            }

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are not using the difference in days in the where clasuse, then it is better to do this calculation in your code instead of adding overhead to SQL, so change your code to:

```
public class democlass
{
 public DateTime DueDate{get;set;} 
 public int count {get; set;}
}

 var result =((from dd in db.vuExpiredProjectsAssigned
            where dd.AssignedTo==obj.DepartmentID
            select new democlass()
            {
                DueDate= dd.DueDate;
            })).ToList();

result.ForEach(a=> {a.count = a.DueDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalDays});
```